# Does a Linear Regression with Residuals not normally distributed useful somehow?

Tags: multiple-regression, linear-model, residuals, generalized-least-squares

I have a linear regression with two independent variables. After running the regression, both coefficients got p-value < .05. Everything seemed ok besides that, the sign of the coefficients were like we expected due to what we know about our product, we thought we were doing fine. However, the residuals seems totally biased.

Here's what they look like:

[image]

**My question is: is this regression still useful? How much can I trust the coefficients?**

I read somewhere that the residuals not being normal is actually not a problem, but I still don't get it.

Well, just so you know, my dependent variable goes from 0 to 1. The variables I have are: (I) the price of the product; (II) how many buyers per product we have; (III) the selling rate. For instance, we have 100 products A, the average price of it is 50 and there are 120 subscribers to our store. So the variable (I) is 50 and the variable (II) is 1.2. If we sold 50 products, variable (III), our dependent variable, is 0.5. I have this data for several products, monthly, for one year of sales.

Comment: Please explain what kind of "regression" this is, what kinds of residuals these are (they don't appear to be ordinary least squares residuals), and what the axes on this plot mean.

Comment: Sorry, it's a OLS, a multiple linear regression. The x-axis is the residual and the y-axis is the predicted value.